# How to use spark-streaming to implement daily compute and get real-time result

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I need to compute "new users, active users" of an app from server-side log.
I have implemented the daily compute algorithm with scala and spark. This job is submitted once a day, and get all results for that day. It works well.
Here is some pseudo-code of my implementation of old daily algorithm. This code runs once a day, and gets a set of daily results:

```
// Get today log from hbase or somewhere else
val log = getRddFromHbase(todayDate)
// Compute active user
val activeUser = log.map(line => ((line.uid, line.appId), line).reduceByKey(distinctStrategyMethod)
// Get history user from hdfs
val historyUser = loadFromHdfs(path + yesterdayDate)
// Compute new user from active user and historyUser
val newUser = activeUser.subtractByKey(historyUser)
// Get new history user
val newHistoryUser = historyUser.union(newUser)
// Save today history user
saveToHdfs(path + todayDate)
```

Now I want to get "real-time" results:
**1. The results should be recomputed and changed every 5 min or less.

2. The results should be 0 at the beginning of the day, and same as my old algorithm at the end of the day.**

I think it's not right if I use a constant time-window(1 day and slide every 5 min, I think) to implement the algorithm.
I will be grateful if someone can offer me some idea or example. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting it from Hbase, you can leverage the following strategy: -

1. [Flume-NG](http://ttps://flume.apache.org) - Install Flume Agents and either "tail" the log files or code your own [Source](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html) for capturing the events generated in real-time.List item
2. [Flume-Spark Listener](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-flume-integration.html) - Follow the instructions as specified and receive the events in Near Real-time (not real-time).
3. Next in your Spark Streaming Code we can create the *StreamingContext* with 60 seconds or less like this:-

   ```
   val streamCtx = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(60))
   val lines = streamCtx.socketTextStream("HOST_NAME", PORT, MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2)
   //Next - Depending upon the format do the further computations 
   //and either print the results or Store in RDBMS/ NOSQL - HBASE/Cassandra
   ```

Comment: Actually I can read stream from kafka and process DStream correctly. I need some help on streaming algorithm, api of spark-streaming and thinking of solving this kind of problem. Maybe you can help me on this question. It's more specified.  [How to count new element from stream by using spark-streaming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786117/how-to-count-new-element-from-stream-by-using-spark-streaming)