# How to count new element from stream by using spark-streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have done implementation of daily compute. Here is some pseudo-code.
"newUser" may called first activated user.

```
// Get today log from hbase or somewhere else
val log = getRddFromHbase(todayDate)
// Compute active user
val activeUser = log.map(line => ((line.uid, line.appId), line).reduceByKey(distinctStrategyMethod)
// Get history user from hdfs
val historyUser = loadFromHdfs(path + yesterdayDate)
// Compute new user from active user and historyUser
val newUser = activeUser.subtractByKey(historyUser)
// Get new history user
val newHistoryUser = historyUser.union(newUser)
// Save today history user
saveToHdfs(path + todayDate)
```

Computation of "activeUser" can be converted to spark-streaming easily. Here is some code:

```
    val transformedLog = sdkLogDs.map(sdkLog => {
      val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
      val timeToday = ((time - (time + 3600000 * 8) % 86400000) / 1000).toInt
      ((sdkLog.appid, sdkLog.bcode, sdkLog.uid), (sdkLog.channel_no, sdkLog.ctime.toInt, timeToday))
    })
    val activeUser = transformedLog.groupByKeyAndWindow(Seconds(86400), Seconds(60)).mapValues(x => {
      var firstLine = x.head
      x.foreach(line => {
        if (line._2 < firstLine._2) firstLine = line
      })
      firstLine
    })
```

But the approach of "newUser" and "historyUser" is confusing me.
I think my question can be summarized as "how to count new element from stream". As my pseudo-code above, "newUser" is part of "activeUser". And I must maintain a set of "historyUser" to know which part is "newUser".

**I consider an approach, but I think it may not work right way:**
Load the history user as a RDD. Foreach DStream of "activeUser" and find the elements doesn't exist in the "historyUser". **A problem here is when should I update this RDD of "historyUser" to make sure I can get the right "newUser" of a window.**
Update the "historyUser" RDD means add "newUser" to it. Just like what I did in the pseudo-code above. The "historyUser" is updated once a day in that code. **Another problem is how to do this update RDD operation from a DStream.** I think update "historyUser" when window slides is proper. But I haven't find a proper API to do this.
So which is the best practice to solve this problem.

Comment: Detail of implementation is good, some idea may help too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updateStateByKey` would help here as it allows you to set initial state (your historical users) and then update it on each interval of your main stream. I put some code together to explain the concept

```scala
val historyUsers = loadFromHdfs(path + yesterdayDate).map(UserData(...))

case class UserStatusState(isNew: Boolean, values: UserData)

// this will prepare the RDD of already known historical users
// to pass into updateStateByKey as initial state
val initialStateRDD = historyUsers.map(user => UserStatusState(false, user))

// stateful stream
val trackUsers = sdkLogDs.updateStateByKey(updateState, new HashPartitioner(sdkLogDs.ssc.sparkContext.defaultParallelism), true, initialStateRDD)
// only new users
val newUsersStream = trackUsers.filter(_._2.isNew)


def updateState(newValues: Seq[UserData], prevState: Option[UserStatusState]): Option[UserStatusState] = {
  // Group all values for specific user as needed
  val groupedUserData: UserData = newValues.reduce(...)

  // prevState is defined only for users previously seen in the stream
  // or loaded as initial state from historyUsers RDD
  // For new users it is None
  val isNewUser = !prevState.isDefined
  // as you return state here for the user - prevState won't be None on next iterations
  Some(UserStatusState(isNewUser, groupedUserData))

}
```

Comment: I think this approach will get new user of the last iteration. But how to get new user of a longer time window? I have tried use "window" method on "trackUsers", and its behavior is strange. All elements seems be copied on every iteration, there appears so many elements. When I use "window" method on "newUsersStream", it seems work well.

Comment: how is your window set? if you have `stream.window(Seconds(10), Seconds(1))` you will "see" each element 10 times as it is overlapping window. If it is `stream.window(Seconds(10), Seconds(10))` you will see each element only once since it is not overlapping. To track new user over longer window you can either do non-overlapping window (this is straightforward) or you can do overlapping and add counter to your state and increase it on each iteration for each new user and consider it not new only after counter is increased to some limit. I.e. interval = 1sec, limit 120sec will keep user for 2min

Comment: I am using overlapping window. Window method actually works as you described. And I found just use window method on "newUsersStream" in your code would work. It will get new user and just ignore the state. Thank you for your help.